# How to access an instance variable from a different controller whose page on which I am rendering a partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a User controller, and a Notifications controller. User has_many Notifications through a number of other models. Is there a good way to define @user in my notifications#destroy action so that I can reference it in my javascript?

On my User show page, I have something like this.

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<div>

  <div id="user_notificationss_count">
    "You have <%= @user.notifications.count %> notifications"
  </div>

  <%= render @user.notifications %>

</div>
```

**notifications/_notification.html.erb**

```
  <div id="notification_<%= @notification.id %>">
    <div>Congrats, you have earned XXX badge!</div>
    <div><%= link_to 'X', notification, method: :delete, remote: true %></div>
  </div>
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

**notifications_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
  @notification= Notification.find(params[:id])
  @notification.destroy
  respond_to |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

**notifications/destroy.js.erb**

```
$("#notification_<%= @notification.id %>").remove();
$("#user_notifications_count").html("You have <%= @user.notifications.count %> notifications");
```

In the javascript, the first line with `.remove();` works fine. However, the second line doesn't work because I haven't defined @user in my controller destroy action. My user model has_many notifications through multiple other models. Therefore, each notification does NOT have a specific user_id. Is there a way to get the user_id params from the user#show page that I am rendered on?

Sorry if I am not being clear. Please let me know and I will supplement with additional explanation/code.  Thanks!



**EDIT: ADDING MODEL CODE**

**user.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name
has_many :articles
has_many :comments
has_many :badges

def notifications(reload=false)
  @notifications = nil if reload
  @notifications ||= Notification.where("article_id IN (?) OR comment_id IN (?) OR badge_id IN (?)", article_ids, comment_ids, badge_ids)
end
```

**article.rb**

```
attr_accessible :content, :user_id
belongs_to :user
has_many :notifications
```

**comment.rb**

```
attr_accessible :content, :user_id
belongs_to :user
has_many :notifications
```

**badge.rb**

```
attr_accessible :name, :user_id
belongs_to :user
has_many :notifications
```

**notification.rb**

```
attr_accessible :article_id, :comment_id, badge_id
belongs_to :article
belongs_to :comment
belongs_to :badge
```

Comment: In `notifications_controller.rb`, is there any way to determine the interceding model that `User` `has_many :through`?

Comment: Please explain how User and Notification are associated

Comment: Hi @zeantsoi. User has_many `articles`, has_many `comments`, has_many 'badges`. A user can get a notification through only one of these models at a time, so I guess I could do something like `if @notification.article_id == nil && @notification.comment_id == nil` then `@user = @notification.badge.user` and cycle through each scenario. Was hoping for a simpler solution though.

Comment: Hi @Vimsha, I added my models to my question.

Comment: @umezo, I think that's probably the best approach. It doesn't add much logic, actually. It's wise to abstract such logic into your model for ease of use/reuse.  I've posted an answer that demonstrates how this can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up a virtual attribute in your `Notification` model would work:

```
# app/models/notification.rb
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :article, :comment, :badge

    def user
        if article_id.nil? && comment_id.nil?
            badge.user
        elsif comment_id.nil? && badge_id.nil?
            article.user
        elsif badge_id.nil? && article_id.nil?
            comment.user
        end
    end
end
```

Then, you could look up the parent in the `destroy` action of the notifications controller:

```
# app/controllers/notifications_controller.rb
def destroy
    @notification= Notification.find(params[:id])
    @user = @notification.user
    ...
end
```

You'll subsequently be able to access the `@user` instance variable just as you've indicated in your `destroy.js.erb` snippet above.

Comment: Works like a charm. By the way, can you think of a scenario under which it would be better to add a user_id column to the notification model and enter the badge.user.id (or whatever is relevant) upon creation?